# How to escape slashes from folder paths in GitLab CI/CD?

Tags: sed, gitlab, cicd

I have this line in CI/CD GitLab pipeline:

- sed -i "s|/xxx/yyy/zzz.txt|${WHITELIST_PATH}/g" .env

also tried:

- sed -i "s#/xxx/yyy/zzz.txt#${WHITELIST_PATH}/g" .env
- sed -i "s|/xxx/yyy/zzz.txt|${WHITELIST_PATH}/g" .env

and all combinations...

But the pipeline cannot execute successfully because:

I guess the problem is in slashes that are included both in sed in CI/CD as well as in variable of CI/CD, ofc I'm not sure.
sed: -e expression #1, char 57: unterminated `s' command

How would you replace string data in .env file that is actually a path which includes slashes?

Comment: If you use `|`, it's `s|<pattern>|<repl>|`, three `|`. `sed -i "s|/xxx/yyy/zzz.txt|${WHITELIST_PATH}|g" .env`

Comment: The `g` flag is often unnecessary anyway. If you don't expect more than one match _per line_ it's redundant.

Comment: Thanks a lot KamilCuk, that was the solution!